# remember me in login form

Tags: asp.net, remember-me

I have a "login" control that I'd like to have a "remember me" option.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading up on the ASP.NET Login Controls.

Read the following, and you'll have the information you need to create what you need:

- [How to: Create an ASP.NET Login Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178331.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Login Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)